# find the set, $\{x\in [0,1]:f(x)\ge\frac{1}{2}\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the function $f$ defined by

$$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, & x = 0 \\ \frac{1}{n} & \text{if } x=\frac{m}{n}\in \mathbb Q \smallsetminus \{0\} \text{ is in lowest terms, with }n>0 \\ 0, & \text{if } x \notin \mathbb Q \end{cases} $$

How do I find the set,

$$\left\{x\in [0,1]:f(x) \ge \frac{1}{2}\right\}$$

Comment: $f(x)<1/2$ if $x$ is not rational number, or its denominator is larger than $2$. Otherwise, $f(x) \ge 1/2$

Comment: Shouldn't there be 3 points?

Answer (score 1):

If we denote this set by $S$, then clearly $0\in S$ and $x\notin\mathbb{Q}\Longrightarrow x\notin S$. On the other hand, if $x\in(0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}\cap S$ then when $x = m/n$ is in its lowest terms, $n \le 2$. Since $x \le 1$, by looking at the two possible cases $n = 1$ and $n = 2$, we conclude that either $x = 1/2$ or $x = 1$. As a result,

$$ \left\{x\in[0,1]:f(x) \ge \frac{1}{2}\right\} = \left\{0,\frac{1}{2},1\right\} $$